# newly added object via form isn't adding in list of state ngrx angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to add new object in existing array readily present in my state. unfortunately I've checked everything, consoled object in reducer where it should to be added in the list.

I checked object at each step, it's present at every stage.

I tried with different techniques to update state but unfortunately not succeeded.

here are my actions

```
export const AddWo = createAction(ADD_WO, props<{ addWo: woList }>());
export const AddWoSuccess = createAction(
  ADD_WO_Success,
  props<{ addWo: woList }>()
);
```

reducer:

```
    on(AddWoSuccess, (state: any, action: any) => {

// console.log(action.addWo) // object is printing as expected.
        return {
          ...state,
          reload: false,
          woList: [...state.woList, {...action.addWo}]
        }
      })
```

here is my effect

```
    addWorkOrder$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(AddWo),
          // @ts-ignore
          mergeMap((action) => {
            return this.woService.saveWorkOrder(action.addWo).pipe(map((addWo) => {
              addWo.id = 40;
// console.log(addWo) // object is printing as expected.
              return AddWoSuccess({addWo})
            }));

      })
    );
  })
```

Comment: are you seeing the AddWoSuccess being called under the redux dev tools?

Comment: yes, it is being called but new object isn't added

Comment: UPDATE: solved by using entity adapters
Entity adapters have many options/methods to explore yet. I used adapters.addOne()